# How to get values from custom sub-annotation?

Tags: java, annotations

I have a question about getting custom annotation value which is value of another custom annotation. For example I have a *`@SqlInfo`* annotation interface which have two values which is also annotation interfaces.

**SqlInfo.java**

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface SqlInfo {

    CodificationInfo codificationInfo();
    DocumentInfo documentInfo();
}
```

*`@CodificationInfo`* and *`@DocumentInfo`* is also annotation interfaces. Each of it has his own different values.

**CodificationInfo.java**

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface CodificationInfo {

    enum KEYS {
        DOMAIN,
        FILE,
        TABLE,
        CLASS
    }

    String domain() default "";
    String fileName() default "";
    String table() default "";
    Class codificationClass();
}
```

While I am using only *`@CodificationInfo`* annotation for the class. I am getting values from it by using this method:

**Annotation values getter method**

```
public Object getClassAnnotationValue(Class c, String key) {
    Annotation annotation = c.getAnnotation(CodificationInfo.class);
    return getObjectByKey(annotation, key);
}

private Object getObjectByKey(Annotation annotation, String key) {
    if (annotation instanceof CodificationInfo) {
        if (key.equalsIgnoreCase(CodificationInfo.KEYS.TABLE.toString())) {
            return ((CodificationInfo) annotation).table();
        } else if (key.equalsIgnoreCase(CodificationInfo.KEYS.CLASS.toString())) {
            return ((CodificationInfo) annotation).codificationClass();
        } else if (key.equalsIgnoreCase(CodificationInfo.KEYS.DOMAIN.toString())) {
            return ((CodificationInfo) annotation).domain();
        } else if (key.equalsIgnoreCase(CodificationInfo.KEYS.FILE.toString())) {
            return ((CodificationInfo) annotation).fileName();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I want to know how to get *`@CodificationInfo`* values while I am using *`@SqlInfo`* annotation for the class? It means - **how to get values from sub-annotation?**

*P.S.: I know that I can use both annotations separately for the class. But I want to know the any way how to get values from sub-annotation. For example hibernate use it for `@AuditOverrides` annotation.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a type declared like:

```
@SqlInfo(codificationInfo = @CodificationInfo(codificationClass = AClass.class)
public class MyType { }
```

you can reflectively get the inner annotation values with:

```
final SqlInfo sqlInfoAnnotation = (SqlInfo) c.getAnnotation(SqlInfo.class);    
if (sqlInfoAnnotation == null) return;

final CodificationInfo codInfoAnnotation = sqlInfoAnnotation.codificationInfo();

final Class<?> codClass = codInfoAnnotation.codificationClass();
```

---

Note: you can avoid having to cast the annotation by not using raw types (prefer `Class<?>` over `Class`).

Comment: It's working as it should. I haven't noticed that the method could be almost the same as getting value from simple annotation. Thank you.

Comment: Note: if you avoid `raw types` you do not need casting. Prefer `Generic<?> g;` over `Generic g;`

Comment: I know about raw types. But if you're talking about `(SqlInfo) c.getAnnotation(SqlInfo.class)` casting, so for me not casted `Annotation` throws an compilation error. But as I see `getAnnotation()` method should cast the Object inside the method. So that's really strange.

Comment: @Dumbo this is in fact a consequence of the raw `Class` type. By using a wildcard `Class<?>` the compilation error disappears...

Comment: Thank you, that info really helpful